# Cant send email subject (dataframe into html) with python

Tags: python, html, pandas, email, python-requests

I try to use python to send email, but in vain. I have already turned the list file into dataframe, then turn it into html form. However, the result show the "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"  What's wrong with it?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(output, columns=['name', 'price', 'count', 'view'])
df.to_html('df.html')

content = MIMEMultipart()  
content["subject"] = "python gmail 測試"  
content["from"] = "dingyen77477449@gmail.com"  
content["to"] = "dingyen77477449@gmail.com" 

template = Template(file:///C:/Users/user("df.html").read_text())

content.attach(MIMEText(template, "html"))

import smtplib
with smtplib.SMTP(host="smtp.gmail.com", port="587") as smtp:  
    try:
        smtp.ehlo()  
        smtp.starttls()  
        smtp.login("dingyen77477449", "password")  
        smtp.send_message(content)  
        print("Complete!")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error message: ", e)
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Not sure what is class `Template`, but you don't have to export to a file before attaching. Simply attach as a string like `content.attach(MIMEText(df.to_html(), "html"))`...